# Why can a website crash the whole browser? (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, browser, crash

What is wrong with Firefox that a simple website can crash it completely?
But not only that.. it feels like every tab runs on the same thread and when one tab does something really heavy all the other tabs freeze for a second.
I notice that a lot when listening to live podcasts.. the skipping can be really annoying.

Shouldn't every tab run completely isolated? What is causing these issues? Is there a way to fix these issues?

Sometimes when you're lucky and the browser doesn't crash, you get an error like this after it froze for 10 seconds or so:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Electrolysis](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis) (Mozilla’s take on process-per-tab) is not yet present in stable Firefox. That means everything runs in a single process and most likely with a single GUI thread.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox) some more (not-so-technical) info.

Comment: Multiple processes? Multithreading can happen in a single process, multiple processes would create a lot of overhead.

Comment: Certainly, there’s some overhead. However, threads are not enough to catch all types of errors. Sometimes it may even be desirable to not catch some errors because cleaning up the state is too bothersome. Multiple processes is what Chrome does and it’s what Firefox will do, soon-ish.

Comment: [Here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=308158)’s some more discussion on the topic.

Comment: Back in the old days, all browsers were single process. Firefox is now one of the last to move to multi-process. The overhead is an acceptable compromise for massively increased performance, security, and reliability.